# Curiously recursive static member functions as template function parameters

Tags: c++

This is a fairly obscure corner of templates but I ran into it and was wondering if I understand what is going on.

So you can have non type parameters to a template, including a function pointer so this is OK

```
using OP = int(*)(int);

template <OP operation> struct Foo
{
    int do_op( int x )
    {
        return( operation( x ) );
    }
};
```

This can be used as follows in a class derived from Foo

```
int add_one( int x ) { return( x + 1 ); }

struct Bar : public Foo<add_one> { };
```

My question is should I be able to use a static member function of the derived class?

```
struct Baz : public Foo<Baz::member_add_one>
{
    static int member_add_one( int x ) { return( x + 1 ); }
};
```

this gives a compiler error, at least on VS 2015 Update 2 RC. So is the compiler correct and if so why?

Compiler error is "Error is error C2065: 'mem_add_one': undeclared identifier"

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: Consider reading the error message. Compilers tend to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Error is error C2065: 'mem_add_one': undeclared identifier

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Baz` that way because it is an [incomplete type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type) at the time of use.
In other terms, when you try to *use* the member method (well, to refer it), you are still defining your class and I strongly suspect the message error is saying you exactly the same.